# I can't get styleable array of attrs

Tags: android, styles, android-styles

I am declaring a styleable view with attrs, and I created the file myview_attrs.xml this simple way:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TestStyleable">
        <attr name="testAttr" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then, I want to load this attr in my code:

```
void loadAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.);
}
```

After *R.styleable.* , with ctrl-SPACE, these are the options I am given:

[image]

That is obviously wrong. Indeed, I can't select *R.styleable.TestStyleable*, because it's not proposed in the menu, but only *R.styleable.TestStyleable_testAttr*, that does not make sense.

Of course, if I choose the second one it gives me error, because a *int[]* is expected and I put an *int*. On the other side, if I manually write *R.styleable.TestStyleable* fails with "Cannot resolve symbol".

What am I missing here??

Update: this ended to be an Android Studio bug.

Comment: doesn't change... not even reference|integer

Comment: Looks like just a bug of Android studio, or smth like that. Try to create a different styleable and check its behaviour.

Comment: There is no such overrided `Context.obtainStyledAttributes` method which takes AttributeSet as first parameter and int as second ...

Comment: Thank you Yurii, that was it.

Comment: Selvin, that was exactly my problem... I could not select int[]

Comment: @Selvin, Not at all :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Yurii Tsap stated, this is an Android Studio bug, and it finally got fixed by making

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart**